# Python calculating grades

Tags: python

```
missing = 0
highscore = 0
inclass = 0
takenexam = 0
count = 0
total = 0

minGrade = 100 #assuming 100 is the highest grade possible.
maxGrade = 0

score = int(input("Enter a score (-1 to quit): "))

while score > -1 :
    if score >= 80 :
        highscore = highscore + 1
    if score == 0 :
        missing = missing + 1
    if 0 <= score <= 100 :
        inclass = inclass + 1
    if 0 < score <= 100 :
        takenexam = takenexam + 1
    # Determine if the score is the min or max score.
    if score < minGrade :
        minGrade = score
    if score > maxGrade :
        maxGrade = score
    # Add the grade to the running total
    total = total + score
    count = count + 1

    # Read the next grade.
    score = int(input("Enter a score (-1 to quit): "))

# Print the results.
if count > 0 :
    average = total / count
print("number of students in the class: ", inclass)
print("number of students who missed the exam: ", missing)
print("number of students who took the exam: ", takenexam)
print("number of students who scored high: ", highscore)
print("The average of all students in the class %.2f" % average)
```

this is how i am currently coding at, i was curious now how i could help this meet a sentenial-controlled loop, also how i could add the average of all students taking the exam?

Comment: doing a straight copy-paste of your code causes all sorts of errors (python is indent-strict for example -- fix your indentation!).  I started to fix a few of them, then I started to find spelling errors in your variables that didn't match what you have in other places in your code... I can't do all the work for you.  Can you clean this up and maybe post the traceback you are getting hung up on?

Comment: Why is minGrade "the highest" and maxGrade 0? Isn't that backwards?

Comment: It was an example inside of the book i followed, i was a bit confused about it but went along with it, I'm assuming this book has a few issues as i found some examples for problems in the back of the book to show the work, and give opposite outputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a delim, make sure that you set it with a while loop.

EX:

```
While X != -1.....
```

You can use an exit code of some sort if the value is -1. But generally that is your delim to end your while loop, otherwise you will have the option to continue adding values. Averages on the other hand are taken from the total amount devided by all of the totaled up scores.

EX:
One student took one exam and Aced it while he didn't take the other. `100 + 0(totalScores) = 100 / 2(exams taken) = .5` otherwise known as 50%. Set a counting variable for the exams taken, and another for the scores added for all of them. This can help you find the average. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you would like to put the following block inside the while loop by indentation.

```
# Add the grade to the running total
total = total + score
count = count + 1

# Read the next grade.
score = int(input("Enter a score (-1 to quit): "))
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that? also i have all of the blocks unindented in the code i provided.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Your logic was almost fine, I had to sanitise for indentation, print statements and some variable names at a couple of places (you used `max Grade` instead of `maxGrade`, `maxGrad` instead of `maxGrade` and so on)

```
#current code
missing = 0
highscore = 0
inclass = 0
takenexam = 0
count = 0
total = 0
average_taken = 0
minGrade = 100 #assuming 100 is the highest grade possible.
maxGrade = 0

score = int(input("Enter a score (-1 to quit): "))

while score > -1 :
    if score >= 80 :
        highscore = highscore + 1
    if score == 0 :
        missing = missing + 1
    if 0 <= score <= 100 :
        inclass = inclass + 1
    if 0 < score <= 100 :
        takenexam = takenexam + 1
    # Determine if the score is the min or max score.
    if score < minGrade :
        minGrade = score
    if score > maxGrade :
        maxGrade = score
    # Add the grade to the running total
    total = total + score
    count = count + 1

    # Read the next grade.
    score = int(input("Enter a score (-1 to quit): "))

# Print the results.
if count > 0 :
    average = float(total) / count
if takenexam > 0 :
    average_taken = float(total) / takenexam

print("\n\n")
print "Grade Result -------------\n"
print "Total number of students in the class: ", count
print "number of students who missed the exam: ", missing
print "number of students in the class: ", inclass
print "number of students who took the exam: ", takenexam
print "number of students who scored high: ", highscore
print("The average grade is %.2f" % average)
print("The average grade for students taking the exam is %.2f" % average_taken)
```

Comment: So is count and inclass going to give the same output then? because we have two of the in the print area, i was just curious if i need "in class" included in my code or not

Comment: @Brandon you were using inclass to calculate those students whose score was between `[0, 100]`, so I let it be there. In your current code, you have some glaring bugs - like counting scores > 100 as an accepted score for average, assuming 0 score means absence - a student might get a zero even if he attempts the test but doesn't score anything. I have tried to keep things as I understood them.

Comment: @Brandon Of course, I wont do your complete home work for you, so you will have to figure out the way ahead from here yourself :)

Comment: haha :). i really appreciate it, other from the bug for someone who scores....

  if score <= minGrade :
        minGrade = score
    if score >= maxGrade :
        maxGrade = score

That would fix the bug though correct?

Comment: @Brandon The code can also be easily optimised to reduce the number of lines/cycles you are using - Example - use `if - elif -else` statements, define multiple variables in one line `maxGrade, minGrade = 0, 100`, error handling for case when user inputs `string` text and so on

Comment: @Brandon move the code `total = total + score` in the `if` statement for `if 0 < score <= 100 :`

Comment: if i adjust my code and re edit it, and send you another comment, would u be willing to review it and tell me what you think. also should i be alter the greater then or equal to example i gave 2 comments above?

Comment: @Brandon No, I won't review it :) Try the changes yourself. Give it all kind of random inputs that are possible. Break it yourself, fix it yourself. You will learn best that way.

Comment: so your saying to replace "if 0 < score <= 100" for "total = total + score"?

Comment: @Brandon No, I'm asking to move it within that if statement (and not asking to do any replacements)

Comment: so your saying this?
if 0 <= score <= 100 :
        inclass = inclass + 1
    if 0 < score <= 100 :
        takenexam = takenexam + 1
        total = total + score

Comment: @Brandon yes, I am saying that. Try it, run it. It *should* work

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick revamp of your code... like ansh0l, I cleaned it up a bit.  I didn't do your homework for you by optimizing anything or make any strong efforts to improve your code for error catching (aka what happens if you don't enter in a number?  --- ERROR!).  But, give this a try.  This seems to work for me, and I was able to get your `print`'s to work.

BEWARE!!!  I use python 2.7, you are using python 3.*.  You'll probably have to remove my `import` statement at the top to make this work for you.

```
from __future__ import print_function

#current code
missing = 0
highscore = 0
inclass = 0
takenexam = 0
count = 0
total = 0
## Setting the initial score so the 'while' condition kicks-off.
score = 0 
minGrade = 100 #assuming 100 is the highest grade possible.
maxGrade = 0

while score > -1 :
    score = int(input("Enter a score (-1 to quit): "))
    if score == -1:
        break
    elif score >= 80 :
        highscore = highscore + 1
    elif score == 0 :
        missing = missing + 1
    else:
        ## Just being explicit!
        pass


    if 0 <= score <= 100 :
        inclass = inclass + 1
        takenexam = takenexam + 1
    else:
        ## Just being explicit!
        pass

# Determine if the score is the min or max score.
    if score < minGrade :
        minGrade = score
    if score > maxGrade :
        maxGrade = score

    # Add the grade to the running total
    total = total + score
    count = count + 1

# Print the results.
if count > 0 :
    average = total / count


print("number of students in the class: ", inclass)
print("number of students who missed the exam: ", missing)
print("number of students who took the exam: ", takenexam)
print("number of students who scored high: ", highscore)
print("The average grade is %.2f" % average)
```

Comment: Justin, where not far enough into python where we learned about breaks and pass, so i don't know if its really something allowed, but overall he said he wanted a sentenial controlled loop with them outputs, from what my code looks like at the moment would you say it meets the requirements or should i look further through my chapters so that i understand the uses of breaks, and pass?

Comment: in this case the `sentinel` is `score`.  So, yeah, you have a sentinel controlled loop.  So long as it is NOT "-1", it will continue to cycle through the `while`.  `breaks` and `pass` are a no brainer.  In this case, we are using the sentinel to BREAK the loop -- AKA You:  "hey, you - sentinel..." Sentinel: "yeah?"  You:  "Are you -1" Sentinel: "Why yes I am!" You:  "Good, BREAK/STOP what you are doing (break your loop) and let me continue on with the rest of my code."

Comment: `pass` is related, but instead of BREAKING the loop it just says "ignore me and move on -- if you start at the top of the loop, I dont care".  It basically does nothing... it's just a way to be explicit in your code so others who read it go "ooohhhh!!!  He meant to pass for all other conditions".

Comment: is the tutorial you are following?  http://chortle.ccsu.edu/java5/Notes/chap18/ch18_2.html

Comment: No i am not justin, I'm currently using the "Python for everyone" book to help further me in coding.

Comment: So i have a question for you, between yours and ansh0l's, what errors are u exactly taking away from, I'm trying to understand this a bit more, because i tested both of them and end up getting the same output for each one.

Comment: *shrug* was just curious; the code has deep parallels to yours (I wonder if the author of your book has any throw with the tut I posted).  All the same.  Don't forget to "check" the correct answer for whichever one solved your problem/answered your question.

Comment: It's best described in an analogy.  What's 3 + 2? It's 5.  Whats 4 + 1? 5 again... what's 2 + 2 + 1?  5 again... there are MULTIPLE ways of coding a solution.  As you noticed, ansh0l's versus mine produce the same desirable output.  It's just a matter of how we got to the same solution.  In my code, I pulled your `input` into the `while` loop because that's where it makes the most sense to me ("while score is not -1, ask me the next score... when it's -1 stop asking me".  So I have it in just ONE place, where both you and ansh0l have it twice in the code.

Comment: To ansh0l's credit he only changed the minimum thus leaving the majority of your code the way you had it.  Whereas I took more liberties and moved things around, added `break`'s and `pass`'s, and some `if..elif` blocks.  The "errors" that we are removing?  It's hard to tell.  The code you posted was malformed (not indented correctly) and you had misspelled variable names throughout.  Overall both posted solutions are an improvement over your original code (prior to you editing it) =P.  If you want to learn what we did, read the code line for line - that's how we all learn (from reading code).